# Read the format of a static library to know how to import it on MacOS

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I have a big library that uses the NDK to run some native code.
With the new version I need to replace a library that was build from the source code with static libraries that are provided as a set of prebuilt `.a` libraries.

I have configured the project to import these libraries like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_definitions(-DNO_USE_SPLICE)
# Provide build env vars for http.c now that we are using shared jitter_client repo
add_definitions(-Wdeprecated-declarations -DVERSION="android" -DREVISION="1" -DPROGRAMNAME="sksdk" -DBUILDLINK="android" -DBUILDTIME="built_at_TODO")
add_definitions(-D_Exit=exit)

add_definitions(-D__UAPI_DEF_IF_IFNAMSIZ=1)

include_directories(../../external/cpp
        ../../external/cpp/libcompany/src
        src/main/cpp)

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        mynativelib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/common_convert_cpp_to_jobj.cpp
        src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/thread_utils.cpp
        src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/utf8_scrubber.cpp
        src/main/cpp/jni_utils.cpp
        src/main/cpp/logging_utils.cpp
        src/main/cpp/android_remote_logging.c

        src/main/cpp/executor.cpp)

add_library(curl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(curl
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/curl/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcurl.so)

target_compile_definitions(
        mynativelib
        PRIVATE
        ANDROID
)

target_link_libraries(
        mynativelib
        curl
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/static/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmystaticlib.a
        ... other libs here. These are fine ...
)
```

When I build the library I get the error:

> ../../../../libs/static/arm64-v8a/libmystaticlib.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here the relevant part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/rrr/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/rrr/myproject/p12345/p12345-android-sdk/sdk/p12345module/.cxx/cmake/release/arm64-v8a mynativelib}
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/rrr/myproject/p12345/p12345-android-sdk/sdk/p12345module/.cxx/cmake/release/arm64-v8a'
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libmynativelib.so
FAILED: ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libmynativelib.so 
: && /Users/rrr/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/rrr/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/rrr/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libmynativelib.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/libmynativelib.so CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/common_convert_cpp_to_jobj.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/thread_utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/cpp_to_jobj/utf8_scrubber.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/jni_utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/logging_utils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/android_remote_logging.c.o CMakeFiles/mynativelib.dir/src/main/cpp/test_executor.cpp.o -L/Users/rrr/myproject/p12345/p12345-android-sdk/sdk/p12345module/libs/routerAgent/shared/arm64-v8a ../../../../libs/curl/arm64-v8a/libcurl.so ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libmystaticlib.a -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -ljansson ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabctytt_wrapper.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libp12345_logging.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabctytt.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabcwebfetcher.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabctargetconfig_core.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabctargetconfig_config_parsing.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabctargetconfig_common.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libp12345_latency.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libabc_sk.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libp12345_http.a ../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libp12345_thread.a -latomic -lm && :
../../../../libs/routerAgent/static/arm64-v8a/libmystaticlib.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Please notice that I'm not sure whether the version of cmake that I'm using is the same as the one used to build the libraries.

I'm using the the NDK: `21.1.6352462`

To investigate the issue I tried some tools that people suggested in similar questions.

With `ar` I get an error:

```
ar -x libmystaticlib.a 
ar: /: Is a directory
ar: adaptive.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: coro.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: curlops.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: entities.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: exception.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: getinfo.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: helper.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: metrics.c.o/: No such file or directory
ar: mm_parser.c.o/: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried with `file` and `objdump` that both do not return any information.

Is there a way to know what goes wrong?